# Exception: action out of range

Tags: python, exception

```py
def main():
 action_type=input("enter action type")
 input_string=input("enter input string")

try:
 action_type=int(action_type)
except:
 raise ValueError("invalid action type")
if(action_type!=1 or action_type!=2):
 raise Exception("action out of range")
elif(action_type==1):
 print(input_string)
```

This gives an output :Exception:action out of range 
when I enter action_type as 1

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, this condition will *always* be `True`, no matter the value of `action_type`:

```
action_type != 1 or action_type != 2
```

In particular, when `action_type` is `1` then `action_type != 2` is `True`. What you really wanted to say is:

```
if action_type != 1 and action_type != 2:
```

Or, to be more pythonic:

```
if action_type not in (1, 2):
```